# Full link urls not being displayed in web scraping in R

Tags: r

I am working on a project that requires me to scrape a website page by page, each page has about 81 links on it. I have to then scrape these links and parse the data within the links. When I try to scrape the links on the first page, it doesn't show me the full address of the links. Here is my code:

```
library(rvest)
main.page <- read_html(x="https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/srch-edgar.    text=abs-ee&start=1&count=80&first=2016&last=2017")
urls <- main.page %>%
  html_nodes("div td:nth-child(2) a")%>%
  html_attr("href")
links <- main.page %>%
  html_nodes ("div td:nth-child(2) a") %>%
  html_text()

sotu <- data.frame(urls=urls,links=links, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

for (in in nrow(sotu)) {
second.page<- read_html(sotu$urls[i])
html_nodes<- (".blueRow:nth-child(3) a") %>%
html_text()
}
```

I keep getting the error that the links do not exist. This is how the links appear in R:

```
/Archives/edgar/data/1347185/000134718517000016/0001347185-17-000016-index.htm
2  /Archives/edgar/data/1347185/000134718517000010/0001347185-17-000010-index.htm
3  /Archives/edgar/data/1477336/000167973117000023/0001679731-17-000023-index.htm
4  /Archives/edgar/data/1477336/000170066717000013/0001700667-17-000013-index.htm
5  /Archives/edgar/data/1477336/000170500217000002/0001705002-17-000002-index.htm
6  /Archives/edgar/data/1477336/000167973117000017/0001679731-17-000017-index.htm
7  /Archives/edgar/data/1477336/000170066717000009/0001700667-17-000009-index.htm
8  /Archives/edgar/data/1477336/000167973117000012/0001679731-17-000012-index.htm
9  /Archives/edgar/data/1477336/000170066717000003/0001700667-17-000003-index.htm
10 /Archives/edgar/data/1477336/000167973117000006/0001679731-17-000006-index.htm
11 /Archives/edgar/data/1477336/000147733617000006/0001477336-17-000006-index.htm
12 /Archives/edgar/data/1679731/000167973117000023/0001679731-17-000023-index.htm
```

Comment: It looks like the links are relative. Just add the page you are scraping to the beginning of the URL.

Comment: As in: `https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1347185/000134718517000016/0001347185-17-000016-index.htm`

Comment: how do I add the main page automatically to every url?

Answer (score 1):

Get the base url of the website and concatenate it with each partial link.

```
baseurl <- "https://www.sec.gov"
links <- sapply(links, function(link) paste(baseurl, link, sep = ""))
```